# SQL conditional where clause not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write a where clause in SQL where there is a date range search but if the user inputs a ticket number it will ignore the date range entirely.

The issue I have is that the date range is not working and no matter what date you enter (without ticket number) it returns all results.

```
(weighing.TicketNo LIKE '%'+ @TicketNo + '%' OR 
(@TicketNo = '' AND [Weighing].[WeighingDate] BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate))
```

Comment: Is it possible that the @TicketNo variable contains a NULL and not an empty string?

Comment: SQL concatenation is the root of all SQL injection evil. Consider what happens if you pass an empty TicketNo: `(weighing.TicketNo LIKE '%%' OR (@TicketNo = '' AND [Weighing].[WeighingDate] BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate))` . That *is* all records

Comment: If you want to use TicketNo as a pattern, pass the wildcards as part of the parameter @TicketNo so you don't have to concatenate strings.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you're right with your criticism, but this isn't about SQL injection ;-)

Comment: @LukasEder are you sure? The result is the same

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Not in my book. For instance, I cannot drop the database by putting any SQL command in `@TicketNo`. So, the result is not the same. From your comment edit, I take that you have noticed the same thing, so we can agree that your *"SQL injection evil"* comment was a bit exaggerated. It's just a potentially wrong predicate :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you enter a blank ticket number then the first part evaluates to this:

```
weighing.TicketNo LIKE '%%'
```

How many records satisfy that? All of them.

I suggest you try this:

```
(ISNULL(@TicketNo,'') <> '' AND weighing.TicketNo LIKE '%'+ @TicketNo + '%')
OR 
(ISNULL(@TicketNo,'') = ''  AND [Weighing].[WeighingDate] 
 BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate)
```

Comment: That does seem to be working. I see what you mean about the '%%', I didn't really consider that.

Comment: Here is the most thorough study ever of optional parameters. Beware because they can have unexpected performance issues. http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html